# How to use Web Request/Web Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, pinterest

By using web request/response classes, i ma trying to login into Pinterest website.. But i am not able to do that as it is giving me 'csrf error'.

Below is my code.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.pinterest.com/login");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myid", "mypassword");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
Console.ReadLine();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: That error is the HTTP response returned by the remote server. You have used the web request API correctly. Find out why the server sent an error.

Comment: @usr I didnt get you. I am not able to find the error. Thats why asked here. Thanks.

Comment: What I wanted to say was that you did not make any mistake sending your HTTP request. The remote server just did not like it.; Use Fiddler to find out what your browser is sending as part of a login. Then, look at the request your code is sending. You'll find a difference.

Comment: Look into Cross Site Request Forgery, pinterest probably doesn't like that you are not sending the cookie it uses to defend against this kind of attack...